# artifacts could not be resolved error while creating Eclipse Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to create simple maven project in eclipse. While I filled in the details and click finish, the below error pops up.

```
Could not get the value for parameter encoding for plugin execution default-resources
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be  resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0-alpha-7, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.6, commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.6, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.6, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1, junit:junit:jar:3.8.1: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.
```

The pom.xml is :

```
<projectxmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">  
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  
  <groupId>ODI_RightNow</groupId>  
  <artifactId>bcone.rightNow</artifactId>  
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>  
</project>
```

I tried creating project using command prompt and that created successfully. 
What could be the issue with eclipse?

Eclipse version : NEON
Maven version : 3.5.0

Comment: can you paste your pom.xml as well

Comment: Make sure the settings.xml used in eclipse is same as you use for command prompt build. If this doesn't work, check the maven install version in eclipse. You can point eclipse to use external version. In addition, check if you specified any proxy settings in eclipse via preferences -> network.

Comment: @AmitK  Added the pom.xml. I tried creating maven project on my personal laptop, and I succeed. This issue I am facing in my office laptop.

Comment: @Shinchan,AmitK  the error is in my pom.xml file. I am pasting the first line of the error showing in pom.xml.

**Multiple annotations found at this line:- Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution  will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.**

Answer (score 1):

@puspen If you could successfully create in your personal laptop but facing error while creating in your office laptop, did you check your proxy configuration in the settings.xml file?

Try updating your settings.xml file with this content only. It worked in my work environment.

```
<settings>
  <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>YOUR PROXY</host> 
      <port>8080</port>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution to my problem. Go to .m2 folder and delete the repository folder under that. Now update the eclipse project , right click project> maven> update project.
This resolved my error. But still in doubt what this actually has done.